# PHP form with while loop

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am having some troubles on generating a page that can print a form based on the SQL query. In this case, what I need is to perform a query to list all the rows of the table where the name is Porcac1x. The content needs to be input fields that show current variable value and that can be updated. This is exactly where I get stuck. How can I create a form which is variable based on the php while loop? With the attached code I am able to list the content and show all the variables but I am having troubles on creating the form action to update the values. I'd like to make clear that I don't care about the security as the code will run in a local environment where I am the only one having access.

This is current output[image] however the save button of course doesn't work

```html
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="$1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <title>test page</title>
</head>
    
    <body><form action="" method="post">
        <?php
        
        
                                $servername = "localhost";
                                $username = "root";
                                $password = "root";
                                $dbname = "root";

                                // Create connection
                                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                                // Check connection
                                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                                  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                                }

                                $sql = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `amount` FROM `expenses` WHERE name='Porcac1x';";
                                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                  // output data of each row
                                  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    echo "ID: <input type='text' name='".$row["id"]."' value='".$row["id"]."'> Title: <input type='text' name='".$row["title"]."' value='".$row["title"]."'> Amount: <input type='text' name='".$row["amount"]."' value='".$row["amount"]."'> <button type='submit' name='save'>Save</button><br>";
                                  }
                                } else {
                                  echo "0 results";
                                }                               
                                

                              
                                   if(isset($_POST['save'])){
                                       
                                    $myID = $_POST["id"];//??? < Issue
                                    $myTitle = $_POST["title"];//??? < Issue
                                    $myAmount = $_POST["amount"]; //??? < Issue
                                    
                                    echo $myID;
                                    echo $myTitle;
                                    echo $myAmount;
                                       
                                       $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE expenses SET title='$myTitle', amount ='$myAmount' WHERE id='$myID';";
                                       
                                       echo $sqlUpdate;
                                       
                                        if ($conn->multi_query($sqlUpdate) === TRUE) {
                                            echo "Record updated successfully";
                                          $risposta= "Record updated successfully";
                                        } else {
                                          echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
                                           $risposta= "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
                                        }

                                        $conn->close(); 
                                   }                                        
                                   
                                ?>
                            </form>
                                
                                </body>
                                </html>
```

Comment: You're missing a form element... To this, you'd either have echo a whole form per row or use the array notation for the name elements on your inputs (```<input type="text" name="element_name[]" value="value">```).

Comment: What a miss! Thanks @MartijnICU!

Comment: I kind of assumed this wasn't meant for production but @Dharman is absolutely right. This shouldn't be used in real life.

Comment: @MartijnICU I doesn't matter whether this is production code or just for you. Buggy code like this should never be written or used in any way

Comment: I want to agree, but everyone starts somewhere... no one writes safe code on their first try. I could also say that it's bad practice to keep your business logic in the same file as your view. But this looks like some one making their first steps into PHP. (no offence @Porcac1x)

Comment: Now that I have added the form (what a miss) the script sends the SQL update just fine, however no matter what save button I press it still execute just the last row. I don't understand how can I pass to the post a random field

Comment: None taken @MartijnICU, I clarified on my post that I don't care about security as I will be the only one updating this data and if anyone will get access to this script/database, honestly that would be the last of my concerns

Comment: Promise us that the permission on your database user are restrictive enough... I know I will sleep better ;)

Comment: Can you update your code in the question? Because it sounds like you have 1 form for all inputs,.

Comment: Done, as you can see where there are comments like //??? < Issue I am not sure how to pass there the real name of the line id, title and amount as the name will need to change based on the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments for this to work, you'll need the array notation. (Or 1 form per row)

This is the solution for 1 form element per row:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="$1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <title>test page</title>
</head>

 <body>                 
     <?php

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "root";
        $dbname = "root";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `amount` FROM `expenses` WHERE name='Porcac1x';";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<form method="post">';
                echo "ID: <input type='text' name='id' value='".$row["id"]."'> Title: <input type='text' name='title' value='".$row["title"]."'> Amount: <input type='text' name='amount' value='".$row["amount"]."'> <button type='submit' name='save'>Save</button><br>";
                echo '</form>';
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['save'])){

            $myID = $_POST["id"];//??? < Issue
            $myTitle = $_POST["title"];//??? < Issue
            $myAmount = $_POST["amount"]; //??? < Issue

            echo $myID;
            echo $myTitle;
            echo $myAmount;

            $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE expenses SET title='$myTitle', amount ='$myAmount' WHERE id='$myID';";

            echo $sqlUpdate;

            if ($conn->multi_query($sqlUpdate) === TRUE) {
                echo "Record updated successfully";
                $risposta= "Record updated successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
                $risposta= "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
            }

            $conn->close();
        }



        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, it looks like the variables myID, myTitle and myAmount are still empty

Comment: I've edited the answer, removing the variable names on the inputs. This should work as expected.

Comment: Not yet I am afraid, the three variables now have 'Array' as value

Comment: And in those arrays you'll find your values.. If you want to treat each row as a single update you should add the form element in your while loop and remove the ```[]```

Comment: Humm if I do that it seems that what ever button I press only the last row is updated

Comment: You have removed the original form element? For your understanding if you Have a submit button within a form (or multiple form elements for that matter) it will submit the form on click. And if you have all these input with identical names in one form each input value will overwrite the previous one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216387/discussion-between-martijnicu-and-porcac1x).